# Where can I find a relatively inexpensive set of Talmud Bavli?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, shas

Product recommendation: looking to buy a small, inexpensive set of Shas (with Gemara) to use on the way to work, on a walk, etc.

I would love for the set to be individual gemara's, not just six seforim, so that the books are not rather large. It can be sets of 20, 30, etc. Ideally also, I would love for the sets to be sized to carry in a standard bag, so not as big as the Artscroll gemara.

Does not need to be english/hebrew, no frills, etc.

Just something I can use to chazar the daf quickly, so not looking to make a huge purchase. Thanks!

Edit: I have found this for $120: https://ozvehadar.us/talmud-bavli-shas-kis-pocket-edition/. Not bad, and pretty cheap and looks easy to carry. Curious if the chevra has anything cheaper!

Comment: You can download a pdf for free, eg. https://hebrewbooks.org/mishnashas

Comment: Can it be used? Try ebay (eg. https://www.ebay.com/itm/393111220820 ) or try a local used seforim store which will surely have random volumes available.

Comment: If you particularly want more, but thinner volumes, then this is cheaper than what you linked to: https://seforimdeals.com/products/talman-shas-katan-20-vol-set-%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%A1-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F-20-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: @JoelK I ideally want more books for individual daf yomi learning rather than bulky. What is Shas Katan? Is that set different in substance than the one I linked?

Comment: In Israel I often saw Talmud "booklets," that is a few perakim on very cheap paper in A4 size. Don't you have something similar in the US?

Comment: @Mordechai It's from a different publisher: Talman as opposed to Oz veHadar. A little more old-school, not quite as modern typesetting, less marginal notes, but otherwise similar

Comment: I believe this is equivalent in size to Talman's (8 inches) but with the Oz veHadar content: https://ozvehadar.us/halacha/rcgam-gulas-alios-mikvuas/

Answer (score 2):

Eichler's has [this set](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/talmud-bavli-teizda-laderech-pocket-size-travel-shas-33-volume-set/34088?gclid=CjwKCAjwqvyFBhB7EiwAER786aKiAivLD1qvbY8MgeGiY_OjdKJFTh9N2feomRE_LxdR8tkFkLr3NRoCEtEQAvD_BwE) for $95.00

Judaica Place has [this set](https://www.judaicaplace.com/shas-vilna-edition-personal-size-20-volume-set-paperback/656043740726/) for $69.99

Greenfield Judaica has [this set](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/vilna-edition-u-vlechtacha-vaderech-travel-shas---20-volumes-paperback-S891137.html) for $59.99

Comment: Is Greenfield Judaica a good place to buy seforim? I'm only familiair with Kehos, ArtScroll and Feldheim.